# How to select features (by polygon) from multiple layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I was trying to export features from multiple layers in a *common* region into new shapefiles after selecting them using the "Selection By Polygon" tool/button. However, the "`Selection by Polygon`" tool only selects features from the top/current layer (QGIS 3/2.99 as of July 2017).

Is there a way to select features from multiple layers (e.g. all visible layers or all layers) by drawing only one polygon?

I don't want to draw the query polygon for the region several times as it is tedious and the polygons I draw could be slightly different each time.

Comment: If you have selected some features in the layer you want to `Save as...`, the `Save only selected features` option supposed to be active (thats how it works in previous versions), so it could be a bug.

Comment: @OtoKaláb Thanks, you're right. There were multiple layers, and the Select by Polygon tool only affected one of the layers. The layer which I tried to export had no selected features. I've edited the question for the new problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have any selection in layer you want to export.

If you have selected some features in the layer you want to `Save as...`, the `Save only selected features` option supposed to be active.